# Routes error on middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello im getting a error of "Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be an instance of Closure", i believe i did everythign well, but still getting this error, what im doing wrong?
My laravel version is 5.2

Code Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'PageController@dashboard');

other routes...
}]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the bracket and it's all good. You passed the closure in the array, when it was supposed to be a 2nd argument.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {
        Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'PageController@dashboard');

other routes...
});
```